# Getting started with ruby God

Tags: ruby, god

When following [this tutorial](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/master/doc/god.asciidoc) on God, I run the command `god -c path/to/simple.god -D` and instead of getting the output as described, I get following weird output.

```
0000000   G   o   d   .   w   a   t   c   h       d   o       |   w   |
              778334023      1668571511      1868832872      2088205344
0000020  \n                   w   .   n   a   m   e       =       "   s
              538976266      1848538912       543518049      1931616317
0000040   i   m   p   l   e   "  \n                   w   .   s   t   a
             1819307369       537535077      1998594080      1635021614
0000060   r   t       =       "   r   u   b   y       /   U   s   e   r
             1025537138      1970414112       790657378      1919251285
0000100   s   /   k   a   m   a   l   /   g   o   d   r   b   /   s   i
             1634414451       795631981      1919184743      1769156450
0000120   m   p   l   e   .   r   b   "  \n                   w   .   k
             1701605485       576877102       538976266      1798207264
0000140   e   e   p   a   l   i   v   e  \n   e   n   d  \n
             1634755941      1702259052      1684956426              10
0000155
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work.

I just ran `god --version` and the output is

```
od (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jim Meyering.
```

It seems it is some `GNU god`. I reinstalled god (`sudo gem install god`) and still I get the above output on running `god --version`. Any workaround?

Just in case: Using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you run the command [`od`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_(Unix)) instead of `god`.

```
$ od -c /etc/lsb-release -D
0000000   D   I   S   T   R   I   B   _   I   D   =   U   b   u   n   t
             1414744388      1598179666      1430078537      1953396066
0000020   u  \n   D   I   S   T   R   I   B   _   R   E   L   E   A   S
             1229195893      1230132307      1163026242      1396786508
0000040   E   =   1   4   .   1   0  \n   D   I   S   T   R   I   B   _
              875642181       170930478      1414744388      1598179666
0000060   C   O   D   E   N   A   M   E   =   u   t   o   p   i   c  \n
             1162104643      1162690894      1869903165       174287216
0000100   D   I   S   T   R   I   B   _   D   E   S   C   R   I   P   T
             1414744388      1598179666      1129530692      1414547794
0000120   I   O   N   =   "   U   b   u   n   t   u       1   4   .   1
             1028542281      1969378594       544568430       825111601
0000140   0   "  \n
                 664112
0000143
```

Fix the typo: `god`

Comment: I rechecked it like 5 times and I am sure I ran the command `god` and not `od`. Just to make sure, I just copied it and pasting it here: `god -c simple.god -D`.

Comment: Ok, I just did `god --version` and I think that `god` I have is some `GNU od`.

Comment: @KamalBanga, Try `/usr/local/bin/god` instead of `god`.

Comment: @KamalBanga, Or, find where the **GNU od** is. (using `which god`). Rename to other name. Restart the shell (or clear program path hash: `hash -r` in bash)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. `which -a god` gives first `usr/local/bin/god` and second `/usr/bin/god`. So doing `/usr/bin/god --version gives `Version 0.13.4`.

Comment: @KamalBanga, Another workaround is adjust `PATH` environment so that desired executable search first.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Just prepended `/usr/bin` to `PATH`.